# How do you integrate $\int x(x+3)^ \left( 1/3 \right) dx$

Tags: integration

I'm trying to do the following integral:

$\int x(x+3)^ \left( 1/3 \right) dx$

It is taken from [this website](http://cow.math.temple.edu/~cow/cgi-bin/manager). According to my source, it is to be done by substitution method. However, when I try that (using $u=x+3$), I have an $x$ term floating around, which is making things difficult.

Could someone explain how this is done? (I'm fairly confident it can't be done by substitution). Thanks.

Comment: If you know how to do substitution you wouldn't have an extra $x$ floating around, because you would replace instances of $x$ with $u-3$. If $u=f(x)$ then $x=f^{-1}(u)$

Comment: I apologize for not being clear. I did substitute the $x$ with $u-3$, but the form of the equation seems similar. It didn't occur to me that the new form can be distributed, while the old one cannot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let $u = x+3 \Rightarrow du = 1 dx \Rightarrow \int (u-3)(u)^{\frac{1}{3}} du.$
Now distribute and solve and change back to $x$.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int x\pars{x + 3}^{1/3}\,\dd x:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> \color{#00f}{\large\int x\pars{x + 3}^{1/3}\,\dd x}&=
> \left.{3 \over 4}\,\totald{}{\mu}\int\pars{\mu x + 3}^{4/3}\,\dd x
> \right\vert_{\mu = 1}
> =
> \left.{9 \over 28}\,\totald{}{\mu}{\pars{\mu x + 3}^{7/3} \over \mu}
> \right\vert_{\mu = 1}
> \\[3mm]&={9 \over 28}\,\bracks{%
> {7 \over 3}\,{\pars{\mu x + 3}^{4/3}x \over \mu}
> -{\pars{\mu x + 3}^{7/3} \over \mu^{2}}
> }_{\mu = 1}
> \\[3mm]&={9 \over 28}\,\bracks{%
> {7 \over 3}\,\pars{x + 3}^{4/3}x - {\pars{x + 3}^{7/3}}}
> ={9 \over 28}\,\pars{x + 3}^{4/3}\pars{{7 \over 3}\,x - x - 3}
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#00f}{\large{3 \over 28}\,\pars{x + 3}^{4/3}\pars{4x - 9}}
> + \mbox{a constant}
> \end{align}

Comment: The answer that I got, which is shown as correct is : $\frac{3}{7}(x+3)^{\frac{7}{3}}-\frac{9}{4} (x+3)^{\frac{4}{3}}$

Comment: @Joebevo Your solution is fine. It's equivalent to the one  I found. We just need to make some algebraic manipulations to see it.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=x+3$, then, $x=u-3$. You are done.

$\int x(x+3)^{1/3}= \int (u-3)u^{1/3}.du $